# Is it possible to create custom AMPScript Function/Method

Tags: ampscript, email-studio

Is there any way to create a function or method which takes parameters in AMPScript which can be called anytime? Example would be a simple java function to called `multiply (a,b)` where the return would be result of `a x b`. Yes, i know i can multiply in ampscript but i explicitly need it within a function call because i will be calling it multiple times for that email.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but you can use Content Builder Assets as code resources that can provide some of the code reuse benefits of using functions.  You just have to standardize variables and naming conventions for the inputs and outputs.

Comment: LOL, I thought this question (and answer) sounded familiar.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs thanks for the response, what do you mean when you say content builder assets? Do you mean Content Blocks?